# how to integrate "giropay" and "sofort-banking" payment in WordPress - woo-commerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, payment-gateway

I am working for German E commerce website, i need to integrate 2 famous payment methods "giro-pay" and "sofortbanking" in WordPress- woo-commerce plugin.

I already asked this to support team of woo commerce but didn't get any reply. So my last hope SO. I know if I get API then may be I can integrate.

If anyone is aware with this problem then please let me know.

Comment: Last hope sounds so close to end. You could well try with paid support I'd say.

Answer (score 0):

**Woothemes** run in their own layer on top of wordpress, and all eCommerce themes run on top of that layer.

It is not hard to follow up a tutorial and implement it in wordpress, but **you should really get an answer from WooThemes**.

Those guys are **great** and I had no problems is any issue in the pass. Send them a [direct email](http://www.woothemes.com/contact-us/) (use the panic button), or send them a [tweet](https://twitter.com/woothemes), they see them all.

And, as a paid customer you do get a better support as well.

or, if you really do not want that way, you can always **search for existing wordpress plugins** that have your providers, for example, [MultiSafepay](http://www.multisafepay.com/en/shopplugins-zakelijk/wordpress.html) has one for Giro Pay.